# Error on executing qplot in R. Statbin requires continuous variable

Tags: r

I am learning R and was trying to generate some histograms. My data set is called "test" and it has a field called dob which stands for date of birth which I am using on the x-axis. I want to show all values from 1:31 in the x-axis. My command is :

```
qplot(x = dob_day, data = fb) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:31)
```

I get the following error in the terminal.

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

I read a few SO posts but could not understand.

Comment: `qplot()` with one argument plots a histogram - is that what you are aiming to do? Then simply convert `x` from character/factor to numeric.

Comment: Yes but how to do that

Comment: as.numeric(fb$dob_day), but make sure it returns what you expected - difficult to comment more without seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized what I was doing wrong
It should be scale_x_continuous command not discrete

Answer (score 0):

"Previously it was used for any discrete variables, whether numerical or non-numerical. Now it is only used for non-numerical discrete variables.
Use scale_x_continuous()"I saw this on Udacity forum